# Microsoft SQL Server Express Replication Error: local publication is missing

Tags: sql-server-2005, replication, sql-server-express

I want to sync. 2 databases using replication in SQL Server 2005. However, after installation I cannot find local publication in replication. There is only public subscriptions.

PS: I am new on SQL server, sorry if it sounds dumb.

Comment: It's not dumb, but you are using an unsupported build of SQL Server. I'd suggest upgrading this. Also, this is better suited for dba.stackedchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server Express can only be used as a Subscriber.  You will need Standard edition or higher to create a publication.  This is covered in [Editions and supported features of SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2017).

Comment: Yes, you are right! In order to create publication, you need Standart, Enterprise or Developers edition.